# How to switch Outlook 365 client account from Basic Auth to Modern Auth without simply adding a new account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, authentication

It seems today is the day Microsoft disabled *Basic Auth* on my account and I have 20 clients to switch to *Modern Auth*.

Anyone know how to switch an account inside the Outlook 365 client from *Basic Auth* to *Modern Auth*?

I'm really trying not to just take the easy way out and create a new account inside the client because it screws up calendar and contacts.

It may not be possible, so I thought I'd ask for the canonical answer here.

[This article suggests](https://www.alitajran.com/enable-modern-authentication-in-office-365-admin-center/) it's as simple as changing a registry key on the machine, but I'm hesitant to try it in a production environment and my test environment can no longer be setup to mirror production. Unless someone can confirm it works, I will avoid this for now.

**EDIT 1**

Adding the registry key per the article above does not work.

**EDIT 2**

It doesn't seem possible to change an existing account. [Adding and removing an account](https://support.mywork.com.au/support/solutions/articles/12000051000-microsoft-outlook-2016-365-workaround-for-this-email-address-has-already-been-added-) seems to be the only way, but calendar and contact data is lost.

The Microsoft Exchange team has spent a lot of time preparing for this major change, but the Outlook client team has failed to implement any solution in their software. I suspect they'll be taking a lot of heat for this in the coming months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to convert an existing Basic Auth account to a Modern Auth account inside Outlook 365.

Comment: According to the official document: Enable or disable modern authentication for Outlook in Exchange Online | Microsoft Learn
When you enable modern authentication in Exchange Online, Windows-based Outlook clients that support modern authentication will be prompted to log in again. 

So you could test with one user first.

Comment: Speaking for the Outlook 365 client, there is no automatic prompt to switch to Modern Authentication.

Comment: So bad. You have to create new profiles?